# To make label text as link

Tags: ios

I have used "Register yourself" as text. I want to make it as link. And by clicking on that link, it should open `Register.xib`.

How can I get this link??

Comment: can't get your meaning. Do you mean how to make a hyperlink on the text, then when clicked, go to Register view?

Comment: It is better to use UIbutton of custom type instead of lablel.

Comment: Sounds like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743457/how-to-customize-uilabel-clickable

Comment: What about just embedding HTML in a small UIWebView? Should that be avoided for some reason - or not possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Kareem is right.  Create a UIButton object, set it's type to "Custom" and then you can give it a title.  Connect the action to a method which pushes or presents your Register view controller and you will be all set.

You'll probably want to give some indication to the user that the text is a clickable link.  Either set the color of the text to blue.  Another, completely separate option, is to use a `NSAttributedString` (which has an underline attribute) to indicate to the user that the text is clickable.  That requires [an Open Source replacement for UITextView](https://github.com/jeremytregunna/JTextView) (which you can learn more about from [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429527/can-nsattributedstring-be-used-to-connect-native-app-actions-with-the-words)).

Comment: I think u are asking for iphone application and iphone application wont display any cursor on screen, right?

Answer (score 2):

I think by below you will get what you want...

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    if ([allTouches count] == 1)
    {
        UITouch *touch = (UITouch *)[allTouches anyObject];
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

        // Convert to coordinate system of current view
        touchPoint.y -= self.bounds.size.height;
        touchPoint.y *= -1;

        CGPathRef statusPath = CTFrameGetPath(statusCTFrame);
        NSString *touchedInterStr = nil;
        if (CGPathContainsPoint(statusPath, NULL, touchPoint, FALSE))
        {
            touchedInterStr = [self getInteractiveStringInFrame:statusCTFrameatPosition:touchPoint];
        }
        else
        {
            return ;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a middle ground that's worth mentioning. Using `UIButton` with `UIButtonTypeCustom` has some shortcomings, namely that you have limited control over the text styling (e.g. you cannot make it right or left aligned, it will always be centered).

Using `NSAttributedString` can be overkill, and tough to implement if you're unfamiliar with `NSAttributedString`, CoreText etc.

A solution I've used is a simple subclass of `UIControl` which allows more customization than subclassing `UIButton` and less hassle than `NSAttributedString` et al. The `UIControl` approach is only appropriate if the entire string will be a "link".

You would do something like this in your `UIControl` subclass:

- Add a `UILabel` subview in the init method
- Configure the `UILabel` with your desired `backgroundColor`, `textColor`, `textAlignment` etc, including changes to the `UILabel` layer if you want the background to appear like Twitter's in-tweet links in their iOS App
- Override the `setHighlighted:` method to customize the look and feel changes on touch/tracking
- Add `@property` setters in the `.h` file so the owning class can set the state

Answer (score 0):

First, construct the attributed string and save the range of the interactive text and the text itself.

Then, draw the attributed string with CoreText Framework, keep the CTFrameRef.

```
CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString);
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, bounds);

CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), path, NULL);
CFRelease(framesetter);

CTFrameDraw(frame, context);
//CFRelease(frame);

CGPathRelease(path);
```

The last, override the [view touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event] like this:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    if ([allTouches count] == 1) {
       UITouch *touch = (UITouch *)[allTouches anyObject];
       CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

       // Convert to coordinate system of current view
       touchPoint.y -= self.bounds.size.height;
       touchPoint.y *= -1;

       CGPathRef statusPath = CTFrameGetPath(statusCTFrame);
       NSString *touchedInterStr = nil;
       if (CGPathContainsPoint(statusPath, NULL, touchPoint, FALSE)) {
          touchedInterStr = [self getInteractiveStringInFrame:statusCTFrame atPosition:touchPoint];
       } else {
          return ;
       }
   }
}

- (NSString *)getInteractiveStringInFrame:(CTFrameRef)frame atPosition:(CGPoint)point
{
    CGPathRef path = CTFrameGetPath(frame);
    CGRect rect;
    CGPathIsRect(path, &rect);

    // Convert point into rect of current frame, to accurately perform hit testing on CTLine
    CGPoint pointInsideRect = point;
    pointInsideRect.x = point.x - rect.origin.x;

    CFArrayRef lines = CTFrameGetLines(statusCTFrame);
    CFIndex count = CFArrayGetCount(lines);
    CGFloat curUpBound = rect.origin.y + rect.size.height;
    CFIndex touchedIndex = -1;
    for (CFIndex pos = 0; pos < count; pos++) {
        CTLineRef curLine = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(lines, pos);
        CGFloat ascent, descent, leading;
        CTLineGetTypographicBounds(curLine, &ascent, &descent, &leading);
        CGFloat curHeight = ascent + descent + leading;
        if (pointInsideRect.y >= curUpBound-curHeight && pointInsideRect.y <= curUpBound){
            touchedIndex = CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition(curLine, pointInsideRect);   // Hit testing
            break;
        }
        curUpBound -= curHeight;
    }
    if (touchedIndex == -1)
        return nil;

    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [interactiveStrs objectEnumerator];
    InteractiveString *curString;
    while ((curString = (InteractiveString *)[enumerator nextObject])) {
        if (NSLocationInRange(touchedIndex, curString.range)) {
            return curString.content;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

You get the interactive text in touchesEnded, then you could do anything you want, like trigger a delegate method.

PS: this is the old-fashion solution, I heard that iOS5 had provided something like an enhanced UIWebView to implement the requirements, maybe you could check the apple sdk document library.

Answer (score 0):

Take a button and set title of the button which you want to set as hyperlink Text. You can choose default and custom button type button in iOS 7 and iOS 8, but for below iOS 7 you have to take button type custom only. You can change colour of the text to highlight text for UI and than add whatever action you want to add on that button click. It will work like charm, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel). Is really simple to configure links, phones, etc.