# Use of undeclared identifier NSLinkAttributeName

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm trying to add a link to an NSAttributedString via the NSLinkAttributeName function, and I keep getting the undeclared identifier error.  I have imported the Foundation.framework and I still get this error.  Here's the code where the error appears:

```
 NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:nonAttrString 
                                                              attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSLinkAttributeName, @"http://www.google.com", nil];
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Thanks,
Pete

EDIT: Clarifictation, the NSLinkAttributeName is the unidentified part.

EDIT EDIT: Okay, silly mistake, the answer is that NSLinkAttributeName isn't in the standard libraries or the CoreText library, so I had to import AppKit/AppKit.h in order to get rid of the error.

That being said, AppKit requires the NSGeometry library which I don't have, where can I find this or is NSLinkAttributeName impossible on ios?

Comment: Which part is undeclared exactly?

Answer (score 0):

[NSAttributedString and Links on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772791/nsattributedstring-and-links-on-ios) this question was already answered, didn't realize it was iOS specific.