# Handle tap on hashtag in iOS application

Tags: ios, twitter, hashtag

I have a question about detect tap on twitters hash-tags in iOS.
Does anybody know how to handle it in IOS?

For displaying messages from twitter I use uitextview.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772791/nsattributedstring-and-links-on-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys on RayWenderlich forum also recommended STTweetLabel. Check it out http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8208

Comment: Or this one - http://www.uditagarwal.com/2013/10/make-different-words-in-uitextview.html; maybe it's same, I'm not check it yet