# Possible to get hyperlinking functionality out of NSAttributedString?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsattributedstring

Is it possbilie to make a hyperlink from `NSAttributedString`? I need to display usernames in a textfield with twitter-like `@username` style and need a call back when it's tapped to dispaly a new view controller. I search the docs but couldn't find anything.

Is this possible, and if not, what are some other alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSAttributedString and Links on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772791/nsattributedstring-and-links-on-ios)

Comment: another option could be UIWebView, depending on your requirements.

Comment: or perhaps make your entire text view tappable?

Comment: @nielsbot making entire textview tappable isn't an option becuase I have multiple @ in the text. UIWebView could work, but is there'a a way I can find out the height of the UIWebView based on the HTML. I am displaying list of comments in a table view so I will need to resize each cell based on the content.

Comment: yes--you can wait for the webview to finish loading, then invoke a javascript call to get the height of the <body> element.. although overall it might be easier to just do your own typesetting using Core Text as suggested by other answers.